# automating file archival from ec2 to s3 based on last modified date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to write an automated job in which the job will go through my files stored on the ec2 storage and check for the last modified date.If the date is more than (x) days the file should automatically get archived to my s3.
Also I don't want to convert the file to a zip file for now.

What I don't understand is how to give the path of the ec2 instance storage and the how do i put the condition for the last modified date.

```
aws s3 sync your-new-dir-name s3://your-s3-bucket-name/folder-name
```

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I understand this wrong

Your requirement is to archive the older files

So you need a script that checks the modified time and if its not being modified since X days you simply need to make space by archiving it to S3 storage . You don't wish to store the file locally

is it correct ?

Here is some advice
1. Please provide OS information ..this would help us to suggest shell script or power shell script

Here is power shell script

```
$fileList = Get-Content "c:\pathtofolder"
foreach($file in $fileList) {
    Get-Item $file | select -Property fullName, LastWriteTime | Export-Csv 'C:\fileAndDate.csv' -NoTypeInformation
}
```

then AWS s3 cp to s3 bucket.

You will do the same with Shell script.

Comment: yes you understood it right, donot want the files to be stored locally rather directly to the s3 bucket. im using a windows OS .

Comment: and in the script that you have given where did you specify the lastwritetime?

Comment: i tried to modify your script..got something . tell me what you think

Comment: $fileList = Get-Content "C:\Source"
>>  foreach($file in $fileList) {
>>      Get-Item $file | select-Property  LastWriteTime,@{LastWriteTime="Age";Expression={(((Get-Date) -$_.LastWriteTime).Days)}}
>> if (Age -le 5 ){
>>   Export-Csv 'C:\fileAndDate'}}

Comment: can you peaase give me a batch script for the same, as i donot have admin access on my machine.

Comment: that script was just example :) .. I didn't mean to confuse you :)  you dont need to export as csv .. you could store in variable and then use another for loop for every file to be copied to s3

Answer (score 0):

Using `aws s3 sync` is a great way to backup files to S3. You could use a command like:

```
aws s3 sync /home/ec2-user/ s3://my-bucket/ec2-backup/
```

The first parameter (`/home/ec2-user/`) is where you can specify the source of the files. I recommend only backing-up user-created files, not the whole operating system.

There is **no capability** for specifying a number of days. I suggest you just copy all files.

You might choose to activate [Versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html) to keep copies of all versions of files in S3. This way, if a file gets overwritten you can still go back to a prior version. (Storage charges will apply for all versions kept in S3.)

Comment: my motive is not to backup but to move the files from the ec2 to s3. copying the files would just not help in cost cutting.